# jquery autocomplete with remote data source does not filter

Tags: jquery-ui

The first implementation works properly.
The second provides a dropdown list, but it is not filtered as you type.

```
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
        source: availableTags
    });
    $( "#tags1" ).autocomplete({
        source: "http://nwx1/mysql/useractivitytxn/f_UsersList.php"
    });
```

...

```
<div class="ui-widget">
    <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
    <input id="tags">
    <label for="tags1">Tags1: </label>
    <input id="tags1">
    <label for="tags2">Tags2: </label>
    <input id="tags2">
</div>
```

var availableTags = [
            "ActionScript",
            "AppleScript",
            "Asp",
            "BASIC",
            "C",
            "C++",
            "Clojure",
            "COBOL",
            "ColdFusion",
            "Erlang",
            "Fortran",
            "Groovy",
            "Haskell",
            "Java",
            "JavaScript",
            "Lisp",
            "Perl",
            "PHP",
            "Python",
            "Ruby",
            "Scala",
            "Scheme"
        ];

the return value from the web service:
["ActionScript","AppleScript","Asp","BASIC","C","C++","Clojure","COBOL","ColdFusion","Erlang","Fortran","Groovy","Haskell","Java","JavaScript","Lisp","Perl","PHP","Python","Ruby","Scala","Scheme"]

```
                    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.22/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="http://jquery-ui.googlecode.com/svn/tags/latest/external/jquery.bgiframe-2.1.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: I even get the whole drop down if I type '3'.

Comment: Selecting from the whole list still places the value in the input box.

Comment: This could probably be deleted since it was answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9349370/jquery-autocomplete-json-source-does-not-autocomplete-but-just-show-the-full  I had an old set of the docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [docs](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#remote):

> When a String is used, the Autocomplete plugin expects that string to
>   point to a URL resource that will return JSON data. It can be on the
>   same host or on a different one (must provide JSONP). The Autocomplete
>   plugin does not filter the results, instead the request parameter
>   "term" gets added to the URL, which the server-side script should use
>   for filtering the results.

Autocomplete can have one of three source types: an array with local data, a string, specifying a URL, or a callback. Your first example uses an array while your second uses a string, specifying a URL, therefore you need to do the filtering and return the filtered result set.

Comment: Hmm, OK. It would be more responsive to put the result in a local array and then let autocomplete filter.  Thanks.

Comment: And that's not very nice if you don't have control of the server side.